# SQLAlchemy simply doesn't update a row and it makes me crazy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I hope you are all ok!!! . Working on Sunday :O!!

I have the next DB named 'books' and a table named equally with the following structure:

```
id
title
author
pages
published
```

[image: Data Base with columns]

I am using SQLALCHEMY to update the title of row id==1, but it doesn't work. There is not errors just it executes normally.

```
engine = create_engine(config.DATABASE_URI)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s= Session()

tabla_libros=meta.tables['books']
stmt= update(tabla_libros).values({'title':'futurehead'}).where(tabla_libros.c.id==1)
engine.execute(stmt)
s.commit()
```

It doesn't update the value on BD nor shows an error.

I appreciate some help thanks!!

Comment: Note that for consistency, you should use either just the session or just the engine (so, `s.execute(stmt)`) but it doesn't affect the behaviour here as `engine.execute` commits automatically.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Effectively, it looks that the error was doing engine.execute() before s.commit() because with session s I didn't make changes so s.commit() revert the changes that engine.execute() did. 
Now when I do 'update' it removes my 2 rows that I had. I don't know why :C

Comment: @snakecharmerb this is the output with 'echo' on engine: https://pastebin.com/RagHa74G

Comment: The session commit would only "revert" if the same row had been updated in the session.  Note that in the pastebin, you drop and recreate the table but you never insert any rows.

Comment: I solve it !!, update didn't work because I was using engine.execute() and a session at the same time, so the changes that I did with 'engine.execute()' the session() reverted(because I did nothing with session() ). It was all about that. A tip for me is not to use both at the same time, just once. 
Do you know the structure to make an update in a session ? instead of using engine.execute(update( TABLE).values({'title':'futurehead'}).where(tabla_libros.c.author=='Ian') )
thank for your help, now I can continue developing my code. HAve a good day !!!

Comment: Write your answer to make it solved !! greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question !!, As @snakecharmerb said as comment. The error is related to use session() AND  engine.execute. The changes that I did with engine.execute() was reverted with session() because I did nothing with the last.

Thanks to all !! have a good day

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you call the following function after you call the **execute or query**
method.

> db.commit()

Example

```
DB_URL = settings.DATABASE_URL

engine = create_engine(
    DB_URL, echo= True if settings.DEBUG else ""
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
 update_user_q = update(u).where(u.id== results.id).values(**values)
            try:
                db.execute(update_user_q)
                db.commit()
```